# Map string to Hilbert curve

Tags: code-golf, string, fractal

Let's map some strings to 2d space, fractal style. Your task is to compute a [Hilbert curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) and lay a string along it.

[image: The Hilbert curve, iterations 1 to 8]

#### Task

The task is to take the single-line input string, and lay it out along a [Hilbert curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) big enough to contain it, but no bigger. Try to make the byte count as low as possible; this *is* [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) after all!

#### Conditions

- Any gaps to be padded with whitespace, but padding is not required at the end of lines.
- The start of the line should be in the top-left corner, and the end in the bottom-left.
- You may create a program or function.
- There may be some new test-cases appearing, so don't hardcode anything!

#### Bonuses

Note: Bonuses stack like this: `-50% & -20% on 100B` = `-20% on 50B` or `-50% on 80B` = `40B`.

- -50% If the input is a multi-line string, reverse the process to create the original input. Test cases for the bonus: just use the existing ones (including the bonus test cases!)
- -20% If you strip all unnecessary whitespace from the output (e.g. at the end of a line).
- -5% If you don't pollute the global namespace (you know what I mean!)

#### Test cases

```
abcdefghijklmn

adef
bchg
 nij
 mlk


The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Thn f ju
 ewooxpm
qckr rs 
ui btevo
    hlaz
    e  y
      do
      .g
```

And for the whitespace-stripping bonus:

```
No  hitespac  her 

Noher

hesc
itpa
```

#### Leaderboard

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 66958; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 43394; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+(?:[.]\d+)?)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

Comment: If anyone can make some more testcases, that would be appreciated.

Comment: So the charactes should be represented by vertices of the curve?

Comment: `No..hitespac..her.` where the dots are spaces would be a better test case for the bonus. (And currently, the test case is missing the trailing `.`)

Comment: If you are taking the L-system approach, you might also want to try [http://codegolf/questions/48697/ascii-l-system-renderer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48697/ascii-l-system-renderer). It could help you to golf your answers.

Answer (score 7):

### CJam, <s>119</s> <s>117</s> <s>113</s> <s>112</s> 109 * 0.5 * 0.8 = 43.6 bytes

*Thanks to Dennis for saving 1 byte.*

Here is a start...

```
{+e`W<e~}:F;q_N-,4mLm]0aa{4\#4e!1=f*\:G[zGGW%zW%G].ff+2/{~.+~}%}@:L/\_N&{N/]z:z:~$1f>sS}{4L#' e]f{f=SF}N*N}?F
```

[Test the forward transform](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B%2Be%60W%3Ce~%7D%3AF%3Bq_N-%2C4mLm%5D0aa%7B4%5C%234e!1%3Df*%5C%3AG%5BzGGW%25zW%25G%5D.ff%2B2%2F%7B~.%2B~%7D%25%7D%40%3AL%2F%5C_N%26%7BN%2F%5Dz%3Az%3A~%241f%3EsS%7D%7B4L%23'%20e%5Df%7Bf%3DSF%7DN*N%7D%3FF&input=The%20quick%20brown%20fox%20jumps%20over%20the%20lazy). [Test the inverse transform.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B%2Be%60W%3Ce~%7D%3AF%3Bq_N-%2C4mLm%5D0aa%7B4%5C%234e!1%3Df*%5C%3AG%5BzGGW%25zW%25G%5D.ff%2B2%2F%7B~.%2B~%7D%25%7D%40%3AL%2F%5C_N%26%7BN%2F%5Dz%3Az%3A~%241f%3EsS%7D%7B4L%23'%20e%5Df%7Bf%3DSF%7DN*N%7D%3FF&input=Noher%0Aw%20%20ee%0Ahesc%0Aitpa)

I'm sure there's a shorter way to generate the curve...

#### Explanation

First, I define a function to trim some element from the end of an array, because I need that in several places. It expects the array and the element (inside a separate array) on top of the stack.

```
{
  +  e# Append the element to the array.
  e` e# Run-length encode.
  W< e# Discard last run.
  e~ e# Run-length decode.
}:F; e# Store in F and discard.
```

Now the majority of the code determines the size of the required Hilbert curve and constructs it as 2D array where the elements are indices along the curve. I construct this based on the following observation:

Consider the 2x2 Hilbert curve:

```
01
32
```

The 4x4 Hilbert curve is:

```
0345
1276
ed89
fcba
```

If we subtract the minimum value from each quadrant (and separate them a bit for visual clarity), we get:

```
03 01
12 32

21 01
30 32
```

This pattern holds for any size. It means that we can construct the next level from the current one, by using as the four quadrants: a) the transpose of the current level, b) the current level itself, c) the transpose along the anti-diagonal, d) again the current level itself. And then we offset them 0, 1, 3, 2 times the size of the current level, respectively.

```
q           e# Read input.
_N-         e# Make a copy and remove all linefeeds.
,4mLm]      e# Take that string's length's logarithm with base 4, rounded up.
            e# This is the Hilbert curve level we need.
0aa         e# Push [[0]] as the level-0 Hilbert curve.
{           e# Store the Hilbert curve level in L. Then for each i from 0 to L-1...
  4\#       e#   Compute 4^i. This is the offset of the four quadrants.
  4e!1=     e#   Get [0 1 3 2] as the second permutation returned by 4e!.
  f*        e#   Multiply each of them by the offset.
  \:G       e#   Swap with the Hilbert curve so far and call it G.
  [         e#   Create an array with...
    z       e#     The transpose of G.
    G       e#     G itself.
    GW%zW%  e#     The anti-diagonal transpose of G.
    G       e#     G itself.
  ]
  .ff+      e#   Add the appropriate offsets to the indices in each of the four quadrants.
  2/        e# Split into a 2x2 grid.
  {         e# Map this onto each pair of quadrants...
    ~       e#   Dump both quadrants on the stack.
    .+      e#   Concatenate them line by line.
    ~       e#   Dump the lines on the stack.
  }%        e# Since this is a map, the lines will automatically be collected in an array.
}@:L/
```

Finally, we use this Hilbert curve of indices to apply the appropriate transformation to the input:

```
\_        e# Swap the curve with the input and make another copy.
N&{       e# If the input contains linefeeds, execute the first block, else the second...
  N/      e#   Split the input into lines. The stack now has a grid of indices and a grid
          e#   of characters.
  ]z:z:~  e#   This is some weird transposition magic which zips up the indices with the
          e#   corresponding characters from both grids, and finally flattens the grid
          e#   into a linear list of index/character pairs. Those cells that don't have
          e#   characters due to trimmed whitespace in the input will be turned into
          e#   arrays containing only an index.
  $       e#   Sort the pairs (which sorts them by indices).
  1f>     e#   Discard the indices.
  s       e#   Flatten the result into a single string.
  S       e#   Leave a space on the stack to be trim trailing spaces later.
}{        e# or...
  4L#     e#   Compute the size of the Hilbert curve.
  ' e]    e#   Pad the input to that size with spaces.
  f{      e#   Map this block over lines of the curve, passing the padding input as an
          e#   additional parameter...
    f=    e#     For each index in the current line, select the appropriate character
          e#     from the padded input.
    SF    e#     Trim spaces from the end of the line.
  }
  N*      e#   Join the lines with linefeed characters.
  N       e#   Leave a linefeed on the stack to be trim trailing linefeeds later.
}?
F         e# We left either a space or a linefeed on stack... trim that character from
          e# the end of the string.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>467</s> <s>434</s> <s>423</s> <s>457</s> <s>451</s> <s>426</s> <s>386</s> <s>374</s> <s>342</s> <s>291</s> 304 * 80% * 95% = 231.04 bytes

The way this works is that I make the Hilbert curve using a Lindenmayer system and follow the left, right and forward instructions along an array of strings. There are probably many ways this could be golfed better, though; especially in the conditionals and in making the array of strings. (I did attempt `[" "*p for i in range(p)]` but strings don't support item assignment (apparently). If I could get that to work, I could get rid of join, too)

**Edit:** Golfed some of the conditionals with thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis). And I golfed down the array of strings. And a no-byte change because the results were coming out transposed compared to the examples above.

**Edit:** Implemented the whitespace-stripping bonus.

**Edit:** Fixed a bug in my whitespace-stripping code for six more bytes

**Edit:** Since this answer doesn't pollute the global namespace, I get the 5% bonus, according to wizzwizz4 [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28529424#28529424).

**Edit:** Changed how `g` is incremented and decremented. Now using `eval()` and `str.translate`.

**Edit:** This answer is now a program instead of a function.

**Edit:** Fixed some bugs from the previous golf.

```python
s=input();m=(len(bin(len(s)-1))-1)//2;t=eval("[' ']*2**m,"*2**m);t[0][0],*s=s;x=y=g=0;b="A";exec("b=b.translate({65:'-BF+AFA+FB-',66:'+AF-BFB-FA+'});"*m)
while s:
 c,*b=b;g+=(c<"-")-(c=="-")
 if"B"<c:x,y=[[x+1-g%4,y],[x,y+g%4-2]][g%2];t[x][y],*s=s
print("\n".join(''.join(i).rstrip()for i in t).rstrip())
```

**Ungolfed:**

```python
# hilbert(it) is now implemented in the code with exec("b=b.translate")

def hilbert(it):
    s="A"
    n=""
    for i in range(it):
        for c in s:
            if c == "A":
                n += "-BF+AFA+FB-"
            elif c == "B":
                n += "+AF-BFB-FA+"
            else:
                n += c
        s=n;n=""
    return s

def string_to_hilbert(string):
    length = len(string)
    it = (len(bin(length-1))-1)//2
    hil = hilbert(it)
    pow_2 = 2**it
    # we use eval("[' ']*pow_2,"*pow_2) in the code, but the following is equivalent
    output = [[" "for j in range(pow_2)] for i in range(pow_2)]
    output[0][0] = string[0]
    x = 0
    y = 0
    heading = 0
    while string: # while there are still characters in string
        char, *hil = hil
        if char == "-": heading = heading - 1
        elif char == "+": heading = heading + 1
        elif char == "F":
            if heading % 4 == 3: y += 1
            elif heading % 4 == 2: x -= 1
            elif heading % 4 == 1: y -= 1
            else: x += 1
            output[x][y], *string = string
    array = [''.join(i).rstrip()for i in output]
    array = "\n".join(array).rstrip()
    print(array)
    return
```

Comment: Curious about the 5% bonus. Are the variables automatically local in Python?

Comment: @edc65 I asked the challenge writer a similar thing here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=28529277#28529277. Hope that helps a little. If not, we can continue the discussion in chat.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>358</s> <s>356</s> <s>344</s> <s>322</s> 319 * 80% * 95% = 242.44 bytes

This is my Python code transpiled to Ruby. I should write more answers in Ruby. It's a decent language to golf in.

**Edit:** I forgot that functions don't need to be named in this question.

**Edit:** Since this answer doesn't pollute the global namespace, I get the 5% bonus, according to wizzwizz4 [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28529940#28529940).

```ruby
->s{l=s.size;m=((l-1).bit_length+1)/2;x=2**m;t=(1..x).map{[" "]*x};t[0][0]=s[0];x=y=g=z=0;d=1;b=?A;m.times{b=b.split("").map{|c|c==?A?"-BF+AFA+FB-":c==?B?"+AF-BFB-FA+":c}.join("")};(c=b[z];z+=1;g+=c<?-?1:c==?-?-1:0;(g%2>0?y+=g%4-2:x+=1-g%4;t[x][y]=s[d];d+=1)if c>?B)while d<l;puts (t.map{|i|(i*'').rstrip}*"\n").rstrip}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```ruby
def map_string(string)
  len = string.size
  m = ((len-1).bit_length+1)/2
  pow = 2**m
  output = (1..pow).map{[" "]*pow}
  output[0][0] = s[0]
  x = y = heading = char_index = 0
  chars_in_output = 1
  b = ?A
  m.times do |j|
    a = b.split("").map do |char|
      if char == "A"
        "-BF+AFA+FB-"
      else if char == "B"
        "+AF-BFB-FA+"
      else
        char
      end
    end
    b = a.join("")
  end
  while chars_in_output < len
    char = b[char_index]
    char_index += 1
    if char == "-"
      heading += -1
    else if char == "+"
      heading += 1
    else if char == "F"
      if heading % 2 == 0
        y += heading % 4 - 2
      else
        x += 1 - heading % 4
      end
    end
    output[x][y] = string[char_index]
    char_index += 1
  end
  return (output.map{|i|(i*'').rstrip}*"\n").rstrip
```

Comment: Is this code dual-licensed under a code license? I'd like to produce a derivative work that's released under the GPL (although any GPL-compatible license will work with this). It's currently released under CC BY-SA 3.0.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Chat here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56405/room-for-sherlock9-and-wizzwizz4

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 227 - 20% : 181.6 bytes

```js
m=>{for(n=1<<((33-Math.clz32(m.length-1))/2),t='',y=0;y<n;y++,t+=`
`)for(x=0;x<n;x++,t+=m[h]||' ')for(u=y,v=x,h=0,s=n;s>>=1;q||(p&&(u=s+~u,v=s+~v),[u,v]=[v,u]))h+=s*s*(3*!!(p=u&s)^!!(q=v&s));return t.replace(/ +$/mg,'').trim()}
```

*Trying to get the 5% bonus*

```js
m=>{for(var n=1<<((33-Math.clz32(m.length-1))/2),t='',x,y=0;y<n;y++,t+=`
`)for(x=0;x<n;x++,t+=m[h]||' ')for(var p,q,u=y,v=x,h=0,s=n;s>>=1;q||(p&&(u=s+~u,v=s+~v),[u,v]=[v,u]))h+=s*s*(3*!!(p=u&s)^!!(q=v&s));return t.replace(/ +$/mg,'').trim()}
```

241 * 0.8 *0.95 : 183.16 bigger

**Less golfed**

```js
m=>
{
  // calc the size of the bounding square, clz32 is a bit shorter than ceil(log2()
  n = 1<<( (33-Math.clz32(m.length-1)) / 2); 
  t = '';
  for(y = 0; y < n; y++) 
  {
    for(x = 0 ; x < n; x++)
    {
      // for each position x,y inside the square
      // get the index postion in the hilbert curve
      // see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve (convert x,y to d)
      for(u=y, v=x, h=0, s=n; s >>= 1; )
      {
        h += s*s*(3 * !!(p = u & s) ^ !!(q = v & s));
        q || (p && (u = s+~u, v = s+~v),[u,v]=[v,u])
      }
      // add char at given index to output  
      t += m[h]||' '; // blank if beyond the length of m
    }
    t += '\n'; // add newline add end line
  }
  return t.replace(/ +$/mg,'').trim() // to get the 20% bonus
}
```

**Test**

```js
F=m=>{for(n=1<<((33-Math.clz32(m.length-1))/2),t='',y=0;y<n;y++,t+=`
`)for(x=0;x<n;x++,t+=m[h]||' ')for(u=y,v=x,h=0,s=n;s>>=1;q||(p&&(u=s+~u,v=s+~v),[u,v]=[v,u]))h+=s*s*(3*!!(p=u&s)^!!(q=v&s));return t.replace(/ +$/mg,'').trim()}

function Test() { O.textContent = F(I.value) }

Test()
```

```css
#I { width: 90% }
#O { border: 1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<input id=I oninput='Test()' value='The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Would it be worth adding `var`s to get the 5% bonus?

Comment: `var s,x,y,u,v,t,p,q,n,h` no it's not worth @wizzwizz4

Comment: You can just put `var` before the first use of each... Oh, that's even worse.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 all in all, maybe you have a point... i'm trying ... no. Too bad